# Laravel Restore a Backup

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm fairly new to server administration. I have my Laravel app up and running and I want to make sure it has proper backups. I have researched some backup packages and I have settled on https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup.

However, once the server fails, I need to know how to use the most recent backup (which will be on AWS S3) to restore the database on the rebuilt server. Are there any suggestions for guides on how to do this? I can't seem to find any unless it doesn't really require much learning and instead just a couple mySQL commands.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use replication and within Laravel i would try to switch connection to the replica database server so things can run smoothly until the problem is resolved.

Take a look at this [Cross-Region Replication](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/)

A typical production environment is automatically running backups on most important things that your deployment needs in order to recover from a failure. Those parts would commonly be your database and storage folder, and configuration files.

Also when you deploy a laravel application there aren't many things that are "worth" backing up , you can choose the entire disk to be mirrored somewhere or you can schedule a backup script which run every N times and backups the things that are more important to your application.

Personally i wouldn't rely on an package from laravel to handle my backups , you can always use other backup utilities, replication and so on.

---

*Update*

Take a look at the link below:

[User Guide » Amazon RDS DB Instance Lifecycle » Backing Up and Restoring
Backing Up and Restoring](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_CommonTasks.BackupRestore.html)

You can call the API function [RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html) as showed on example.

But i don't think something automated exists that would auto restore or magically make everything work, you need to do a lot of security checks if something like that would even be attempted. Final word i believe a good solution manually entering or sending the request would be the most solid solution.

Comment: I have thought about master-slave replication. But what about the actual process of restoring the master? That's what I'm trying to understand, the actual process to restore the master server once it goes down. Thanks!

Comment: @MattPierce take a look at the updated answer, if you use don't use Amazon web services, and you just use an MySQL installation consider using solutions such virtualization and run MySQL instances on that, take regular snapshots to maintain a fresh copy, or if you don't use virtualization try to just backup the entire MySQL databases , when it fails , fix the problem, and then restore.

Honestly there are many solutions when you want to achieve backing/restoring databases and files. If you want to be as safe as possible hire an system administrator which has better knowledge.